# Embedding a facebook application in a facebook fanpage

Tags: facebook

Was looking around for this one, but couldn't get hold of an answer yet. So is it possible to embed a facebook application inside a facebook fan page. For example on a AwesomePhotographer page , I click on games and you can play a facebook game on the game tab in the Awesome photographer page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you begin for this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/